# How do I troubleshoot an "Undefined variable" notice in PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have two models: 'gallery' and 'image'.  When I try to fetch images from the galleries_controller I see this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: images [APP\controllers\galleries_controller.php, line 25]

I use CakePHP's `find` method to limit the images results.

Here is my galleries_controller:

```
function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid image', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('gallery', $this->Galley->read(null, $id));
    /// this code have some problem ///
    $this->loadModel('image');
    $Images=  $this->Image->find('all',
        array(
            'limit' => 2, //int
        )
    );
    $this->set('images', $images);
}
```

Comment: `$this->loadModel('image');` are the line 25?

Comment: $this->set('images', $images); in the line 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable name is case sensitive ($Images and $images need to be all lowercase or all uppercase)

```
// you have a UPPERCASE I    
$Images = $this->Image->find([...]

// you have a lowercase I
$this->set('images', $images);
```

Comment: thanks gabler..please another question..are you have any method beside this method to find limit images or it is the best way

Comment: Don't know, sorry. I don't use CakePHP anymore, now I'm learning Zend Framework 2 =)

Answer (score 1):

Check your capitalization...

```
$Images=  $this->Image->find('all',
...
$this->set('images', $images);
```

$Images != $images